# Arranging Points Uniformly on the Unit Sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization, quadratic-programming

What is $\min\limits_{{v_i\in R^m,\ \|v_i\|=1,}\atop{i\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}}}\max\limits_{i,j}v_i^Tv_j$ where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Euclidean length? Basically, I would like to distribute a given finite number of unit points "uniformly" on a unit sphere.

A computationally easier formulation is 
$$\max_{{v_i\in R^m,\ \|v_i\|=1,}\atop{i\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}}}\sum_{i,j}\|v_i-v_j\|^2.$$

Are these the two formulations equivalent? My guess is that they are not. Can anyone give a proof either way?

Comment: Hard problem. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805583/dispersing-n-points-uniformly-on-a-sphere